# React Native useEffect not being called after render (using proper dependencies)

Tags: react-native, use-effect

I'm surprised with a different behaviour between `useEffect` in web and mobile. After rendering a component, I'd expect `useEffect` to be called. And it does on web. See this code snippet:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-usestate-and-useeffect-m20dv?fontsize=14

I'm posting the code also here for you to see it at first glance.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function useAttemptToSaveCapture() {
  const [shouldCheckPermission, setShouldCheckPermissionFlag] = useState(false);

  console.log("shouldCheckPermission", shouldCheckPermission);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Running AttemptToSaveCapture Effect!");
    return () => console.log("cleaning effect...");
  }, [shouldCheckPermission]);

  return { setShouldCheckPermissionFlag };
}

function useCapture() {
  const { setShouldCheckPermissionFlag } = useAttemptToSaveCapture();

  const onSaveCapture = useCallback(() => {
    console.log("-----------------");
    console.log("button clicked...");

    setShouldCheckPermissionFlag(true);
  }, [setShouldCheckPermissionFlag]);

  return { onSaveCapture };
}

function App() {
  console.log("rendering...");
  const { onSaveCapture } = useCapture();

  return <button onClick={onSaveCapture}>content</button>;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

So, the important code is this chunk:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Running AttemptToSaveCapture Effect!");
    return () => console.log("cleaning effect...");
  }, [shouldCheckPermission]);
```

As I said, running this code snippet in the web I get the expected result: `useEffect` is called after I click the button, because that triggers a re-render. But the same code in **React Native** will not. Or, actually, it will after 30 seconds more or less (when my cell phone dims to save energy).

Apart from the view tags, the code is the same, see:

```
import React, {Fragment, useState, useCallback, useRef, useEffect} from 'react';
import {PermissionsAndroid, StyleSheet, Button, View, Text} from 'react-native';

function useAttemptToSaveCapture() {
  const [shouldCheckPermission, setShouldCheckPermissionFlag] = useState(false);

  console.log('shouldCheckPermission', shouldCheckPermission);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Running AttemptToSaveCapture Effect!');
    return () => console.log('cleaning effect...');
  }, [shouldCheckPermission]);

  return {setShouldCheckPermissionFlag};
}

function useCapture() {
  const {setShouldCheckPermissionFlag} = useAttemptToSaveCapture();

  const onSaveCapture = useCallback(() => {
    console.log('-----------------');
    console.log('button clicked...');

    setShouldCheckPermissionFlag(true);
  }, [setShouldCheckPermissionFlag]);

  return {onSaveCapture};
}

function App() {
  console.log('rendering...');
  const {onSaveCapture} = useCapture();

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Button onPress={onSaveCapture} title="Save" />
      <View style={styles.capture}>
        <Text style={styles.content}>Capture</Text>
      </View>
    </Fragment>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  capture: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#313131',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  content: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 40,
  },
});

export default App;
```

All I've read about hooks assures me this code should work just fine. By other hand, all I've found regarding React Native are examples using *life cycle methods*. Maybe hooks are not being used for react native yet? I can't find an explanation for this behaviour inconsistency. Any clue?

---

UPDATE: I've found that it also works with AVD and with a snack snippet: https://snack.expo.io/SkuxEfPNr . It just won't work on a real phone.